# Recovering Files from Broken Screen Nexus 5x

Tags: data-recovery, nexus-5x, nexus

I have a Nexus 5x that has an unresponsive and broken display (screen displays colored lines and doesn't respond to any touches) that I am trying to get files off of.  I can't seem to get my computer to recognize it, presumably because you need the phone to be unlocked, but i cant get through the lock screen without touching the display.  Is there any way to unlock my screen through recovery mode or something without wiping it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you think the device boots up normally (e.g. does the phone show up in a Wifi if Wifi is enabled?)? Is the device locked via pattern/PIN/password? Have you tried to connect an USB keyboard via USB-OTG adapter?

Comment: It does boot up normally, I just can't interact with it, and yes its a PIN.  I have not tried a keyboard, do you think I could enter a pin with that?

Comment: I never tried it, but AFAIK it should work at least on some devices. Before entering the PIN press `SPACE` and in the end press `RETURN`. Theoretically it should be even possible to navigate blind through Android using keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: check if adb is working from `adb devices` (maybe you previously left USB-debugging enabled), and check if bootloader is maybe already unlocked from `fastboot oem device-info` (after starting into bootloader with Vol down + Power) just to gather options. at least you can get a second Nexus 5x, get two USB-OTG adapters,  tape together two mouses each connected to one phone, set the same pin, and unlock both in parallel with both mouses. Then enable USB-debugging (still "blind"), and then you finally can use scrcpy to cast the screen to PC

Comment: the solution from @Robert seems to be the best. buy a "Micro USB OTG Charge HUB", connect keyboard and use earphones to check key feedback. Post your Android Version. Then SOMEBODY with Nexus 5x please post the proper key sequence https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Z3-Compact/Enabling-USB-debugging-with-OTG-keyboard-without-seeing-the/m-p/1301419#M27733 to enable Developer settings and USB-debugging here?

Comment: also key sequence for accepting the RSA key fingerprint is required https://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2 before you can use scrcpy https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc