# Android screen is dark, no USB debugging is enabled, how can I recover contacts?

Tags: backup, usb-debugging

My phone screen is not showing anything, although the touch detector works perfectly. I hear the sound of the notifications and call and I can answer them but it shows nothing.

What are my options for recovering my log and contacts, I read that I need to root the phone since USB debugging is not enabled for me, is it possible to pull the database files from the phone's storage and extract the data from them, or are they encrypted ?

PS: (my phone is Samsung J2)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213373/recovering-files-from-soft-bricked-nexus-5x#comment273103_213373

Comment: @AlexMyers No they are not syned, is there any hope ?

Comment: You need to find someone figuring it out for J2 https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Z3-Compact/Enabling-USB-debugging-with-OTG-keyboard-without-seeing-the/m-p/1301419#M27733

Comment: Unfortunately your phone does not support MHL. With MHL support you can try "Micro USB OTG Charge HUB" + "MHL micro USB to HDMI converter" + Monitor/TV + Keyboard + Mouse